# Extract current fiscal week for current year in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date

I have a table with fields fiscal week and date in **PostgreSQL**.

For eg: for date 2015-10-10, it has fiscal week values as 1,2,3..39,40,41,42,etc and similarly for other dates 2014-10-10 it has fiscal week values as 1,2,3..39,40,41,42,etc and same for the year 2013-10-10 and so on... I want to extract the current fiscal week for the current year. As there are multiple fiscal week values for different year and dates , it should extract only for the **current** **fiscal week**.

Comment: How is a fiscal week defined?

Comment: A fiscal week is like a fiscal year. It is a week in which the first day of the week is different than a calendar week.A fiscal week can start on any day from the fiscal year.

Comment: Can I use max of fiscal week to get the current week ? and how do I extract current year ? Extract year using date_part from the current_date and then how do I compare current year and date from the table field...?

Comment: Clear as mud. How is the fiscal year defined? In many cases it is 1 Jan - 31 Dec, but sometimes 1 July - 30 June or something completely different. You need to specify that. Then also define how a fiscal week relates to a fiscal year. Look up the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) about date/time data types for the ISO8601 standard that PG supports. And don't ask additional questions in a comment, edit your question instead.